# 'docker history' command: Why does the column label say 'IMAGE' when the column contains layers?

Tags: docker

I have been working with Docker for some months now quite intensively, and I have not used the `docker history` command often (yet).

However, the handful of times I have used it have caused me to develop an assumption that there are a large number of 'dependent **images**' associated with my 'top-level' image, not **layers**.

Now I have come to understand that much of the above assumption was based on the fact that, starting long ago, when I issue the `docker history` command, the title of the leftmost column is **IMAGE**, whereas in fact, the rows really list the **layers** associated with a single image, not images.

Here is a screenshot of an example `docker history` command:
[image: 'IMAGE', not 'LAYER']

There is a critical difference between **images** and **layers** in Docker, which is why this really stands out as a serious question.

I am frankly very surprised by this issue.  How could something of such critical importance be flaked out on by Docker?

I have just spent a while hunting around for a discussion of, or answer to, this issue.  Surprisingly, even the [Docker 'history' command documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/history/) makes no mention of this.  The only real 'confirmation' I have seen comes from [this link](http://blog.arungupta.me/show-layers-of-docker-image/).

Can somebody please tell me why the title of the column from `docker history` is 'IMAGE', while the entries themselves are layers?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's complicated ;) [This post by Nigel Brown](https://windsock.io/explaining-docker-image-ids/) is *super* useful for understanding this, but I'll pull out the relevant points here.

> Historically (pre Docker v1.10), each time a new layer was created as a result of a commit action, Docker also created a corresponding image, which was identified by a randomly generated 256-bit UUID, usually referred to as an image ID (presented in the UI as either a short 12-digit hex string, or a long 64-digit hex string).

So, historically they *were* images, just intermediate ones with no 'human-friendly' tag (although they could be tagged).

> Since Docker v1.10, generally, images and layers are no longer synonymous. Instead, an image directly references one or more layers that eventually contribute to a derived container's filesystem.

And if you do a `docker history` on a pulled image, you'll see something like (taken from the article):

```
$ docker history swarm
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      
SIZE                COMMENT  
c54bba046158        9 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) CMD ["--help"]                0 B  
<missing>           9 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENTRYPOINT &{["/swarm"]}      0 B  
<missing>           9 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) VOLUME [/.swarm]              0 B  
<missing>           9 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) EXPOSE 2375/tcp               0 B  
<missing>           9 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV SWARM_HOST=:2375          0 B  
<missing>           9 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:b76b2255a3b423981a   0 B  
<missing>           9 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:5acf949e76228329d   277.2 kB  
<missing>           9 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:a2157cec2320f541a   19.06 MB
```

You'll see the `IMAGE` column reports `<missing>`, these are not images, but layers that are constituent parts of the image.

So they're not images! What the hell, why is the column named that? (back to your original question). Well, except...:

> However, when a layer is committed during an image build on a local Docker host, an 'intermediate' image is created at the same time. Just like all other images, it has a configuration item which is a list of the layer digests that are to be incorporated as part of the image, and its ID or digest contains a hash of the configuration object. Intermediate images aren't tagged with a name, but, they do have a 'Parent' key, which contains the ID of the parent image.

So actually, when you build *locally*, those constituent layers *are* images (just like they used to be, even when you pulled them from somewhere else, until v1.10), and are used to facilitate the build cache (part that makes builds fast if you've already built that layer already).

So the answer is...sometimes they are images (technically), sometimes they are layers (and then represented in that column as `<missing>`). I'd guess it was left as `IMAGE` for a) historical reasons and b) because they actually are images when something appears there, otherwise it just shows `<missing>`. I can see how they might be a little confusing, and there certainly might be additional technical detail I've glossed over here, but hope it helps!

*Disclaimer: I work for Docker, but my views / posts are my own, etc...*

Comment: Is there any way to get the image IDs in place of `<missing>`?

Answer (score 5):

As John mentions, those actually are image id's, resulting from your local builds. The layers are buried a bit deeper and you can see those building up if you inspect each consecutive image id. Here's an image I have built locally:

```
$ docker history bmitch3020/terraform-ansible
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
c68a76df6362        2 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENTRYPOINT ["terraform"]     0B
32b9c2451d45        2 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:a8a964b6da98146c…   62.7MB
13543af79664        2 months ago        |1 ANSIBLE_KEY_ID=93C4A3FD7BB9C367 /bin/sh -…   80.8MB
e5c0db134950        2 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ARG ANSIBLE_KEY_ID=93C4A3…   0B
e5153922f57d        2 months ago        /bin/sh -c apt-get update  && DEBIAN_FRONTEN…   85.9MB
874e27b628fd        5 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["bash"]                 0B
<missing>           5 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:a71e077a42995a68f…   100MB
```

Now lets go through each of those images to see the layers (this is just a loop on `docker inspect` to look at the "RootFS -> Layers" section):

```
$ docker history bmitch3020/terraform-ansible -q \
  | while read image_id; do \
    echo "$image_id"; \
    if [ "$image_id" != "<missing>" ]; then \
      docker inspect "$image_id" --format '{{json .RootFS.Layers}}' | jq .; \
    fi; \
  done

c68a76df6362
[
  "sha256:a75caa09eb1f7d732568c5d54de42819973958589702d415202469a550ffd0ea",
  "sha256:092445cb4dbd94421917ec3db5b8d0ee2feac691d0555e24f1b7e3451b2f9caa",
  "sha256:4d221bea3442fd038aa42722b44c6633ddbd02e8d4eda1af0c84e5ef7deffe5f",
  "sha256:bd39a8a25e0f87ef27495bd23f57f651b972139c11fd05c8cd7ca79e67549ad2"
]
32b9c2451d45
[
  "sha256:a75caa09eb1f7d732568c5d54de42819973958589702d415202469a550ffd0ea",
  "sha256:092445cb4dbd94421917ec3db5b8d0ee2feac691d0555e24f1b7e3451b2f9caa",
  "sha256:4d221bea3442fd038aa42722b44c6633ddbd02e8d4eda1af0c84e5ef7deffe5f",
  "sha256:bd39a8a25e0f87ef27495bd23f57f651b972139c11fd05c8cd7ca79e67549ad2"
]
13543af79664
[
  "sha256:a75caa09eb1f7d732568c5d54de42819973958589702d415202469a550ffd0ea",
  "sha256:092445cb4dbd94421917ec3db5b8d0ee2feac691d0555e24f1b7e3451b2f9caa",
  "sha256:4d221bea3442fd038aa42722b44c6633ddbd02e8d4eda1af0c84e5ef7deffe5f"
]
e5c0db134950
[
  "sha256:a75caa09eb1f7d732568c5d54de42819973958589702d415202469a550ffd0ea",
  "sha256:092445cb4dbd94421917ec3db5b8d0ee2feac691d0555e24f1b7e3451b2f9caa"
]
e5153922f57d
[
  "sha256:a75caa09eb1f7d732568c5d54de42819973958589702d415202469a550ffd0ea",
  "sha256:092445cb4dbd94421917ec3db5b8d0ee2feac691d0555e24f1b7e3451b2f9caa"
]
874e27b628fd
[
  "sha256:a75caa09eb1f7d732568c5d54de42819973958589702d415202469a550ffd0ea"
]
<missing>
```

You can see a few things from the above inspect outputs, working from the bottom up:

- "missing": This line is because this part of the image history was built remotely and the cached intermediate images are not on the local docker host.
- 874e27b628fd: This comes from the docker pull of an upstream image.
- e5153922f57d: We add another layer on this with some package installs.
- e5c0db134950: This "nop" doesn't create another layer, but it does create another image id. That image id contains some changed metadata, the "arg", that can be used by later builds as a cache if it matches the arg value.
- 13543af79664: Now we have two added layers to the image from the original pull.
- 32b9c2451d45: The `COPY` adds a layer and is tracked by the hash of the files being added from the cache.
- c68a76df6362: This again creates another image id without creating another filesystem layer. The image id contains updated metadata, the entrypoint value, and this final image id is what my tag points to.

Comment: I'm interested to know if any/all intermediate images created locally during a build, but not corresponding to the final image of the given Dockerfile, are pushed to Docker Hub with a `push`.  If intermediates are pushed, but only some, what determines which are pushed?  I know this wasn't my question, but I'm having a hard time finding clear documentation about this, even on the Docker website.

Comment: All of the history is pushed, and all of the filesystem layers will be too. But only the final image id will have an image id on the local docker host.